# Error when overriding props in React.cloneElement()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, overriding

I'm new to ReactJS and recently trying to work out a sidebar component.
I have two react components (**SidebarNav** and **SidebarNavItem**) which can be nested with each other to display a structured sidebar menu.

**SidebarNav**

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class SidebarNav extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        level: PropTypes.number,
        children: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
            React.PropTypes.object,
            PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)
        ])
    };

    render() {

        const {level, children} = this.props;

        const currentLevel = !level ? 1 : level;

        let navClass;
        switch (currentLevel) {
            case 1:
                navClass = 'tfmenu';
                break;
            case 2:
                navClass = 'nav-second-level collpase in';
                break;
            default:
                navClass = 'nav-third-level collpase in';
        }

        return (
            <ul className={'nav ' + navClass}>
                {React.Children.map(children, element => {
                    return React.cloneElement(element, {level: currentLevel});
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

**SidebarNavItem**

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class SidebarNavItem extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        href: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        iconClass: PropTypes.string,
        level: PropTypes.number,
        children: PropTypes.object
    };

    render() {

        const {title, href, iconClass, level, children} = this.props;

        return (
            <li>
                <a href={href}>
                    {iconClass && level === 1 && <i className={'fa ' + iconClass}></i>}

                    {level === 1 ? <span className="nav-label">{title}</span> : {title}}

                    {level === 2 && children && <span className="fa arrow"></span>}

                    {'level: ' + level}
                </a>

                {children && React.cloneElement(children, {level: level + 1})}
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```

The problem seems exists in the line:

```
{children && React.cloneElement(children, {level: level + 1})}
```

I'd like to explain here. The *level* prop is used to distinguish how deep the sidebar item lays so that different styles can be applied. When I tried to test the component with following code.

```
<SidebarNav>
  <SidebarNavItem href="/portal" title="Portal" iconClass="fa-home">
    <SidebarNav>
      <SidebarNavItem href="/portal/home1" title="Home1" />
      <SidebarNavItem href="/portal/home2" title="Home2" />
    </SidebarNav>
  </SidebarNavItem>
  <SidebarNavItem href="/signin" title="Signin" iconClass="fa-home" />
</SidebarNav>
```

I got the following errors.

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found:
>   object with keys {title}). If you meant to render a collection of
>   children, use an array instead or wrap the object using
>   createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method
>   of `SidebarNavItem`.

Does anyone know what's going wrong with my code? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in this line `{level === 1 ? <span className="nav-label">{title}</span> : {title}}`. It has to be react element (or primitive value) instead of `{title}`

Answer (score 0):

Some syntax issue with your code, { } is used for variables or functions

You can:

```
generate(){
    return (<span>something</span>);
}

render(){
    var abc = (<span>something</span>);
    return (
        <div>
        {abc}
        {this.generate()}
        {abc || this.generate()} 
        </div>
    );
}
```

You may want to take a look at those examples from react router to see how they actually implement nav side bar. Specifically the sidebar example.

[react examples](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The example is really helping.

Comment: actually you can also use **{ }** for primitive values: _{ 'string value' }_ or _{ 1 }_, etc ...

the **{ }** are used for interpolation